Who has written this Krishna Chalisa?
I have found that there are two Krishna Chalisa.
Among them I found this one to be the most popular.
I want to know who has written it. And if it has some religious significance like Hanuman Chalisa or is it just normally written devotional song

बंशी शोभित कर मधुर, नील जलद तन श्याम । अरुण अधर जनु बिम्बफल, नयन कमल
अभिराम ॥
पूर्ण इन्द्र, अरविन्द मुख, पीताम्बर शुभ साज । जय मनमोहन मदन छवि,
कृष्णचन्द्र महाराज ॥
जय यदुनंदन जय जगवंदन । जय वसुदेव देवकी नन्दन ॥
जय यशुदा सुत नन्द दुलारे । जय प्रभु भक्‍तन के दृग तारे ॥
जय नट-नागर, नाग नथैया । कृष्ण कन्हैया धेनु चरैया ॥
पुनि नख पर प्रभु गिरिवर धारो । आओ दीनन कष्ट निवारो ॥
वंशी मधुर अधर धरि टेरौ । होवे पूर्ण विनय यह मेरौ ॥
.....


As I have already stated before, chalisas are religious paens written in Hindi. This sort of literature is exclusively meant for spreading religious knowledge aming those who were denied learning Sanskrit texts by the brahmanas. Padma Purana clearly states that it is impossible to get punya  from recitation of scriptures in languages other than Sanskrit. And even for the Hanumanachalisa, nobody outside the Ramanandi sampradaya is bound to believe in its efficacy, just like nobody outside the Srivaishnava sampradaya believes the Nalayira Divya Prabandha to be on par with the Vedas.

The fact that non-Ramanandis are quote-unquote 'made' to believe in the efficacy of Hanumanachalisa has nothing to do with scriptural sanction & everything with imposition of majoritarianism driven cultural hegemony.
